# Gorm load related Data

Tags: go, orm, revel, go-gorm

playing around with the golang gorm orm, I have the following problem of comprehension:

My model looks like:

```
package models

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)

type Book struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title       string `gorm:"size:255;not null;"`
    Desctiption string
    Tags        []Tag `gorm:"many2many:book_tags;"`
}

type Tag struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
}
```

I use this in my revel controller, like this:

```
import (
    "github.com/foobar/myrevel/app/models"
    "github.com/revel/revel"
)

type Book struct {
    GormController
}

func (c Book) Books() revel.Result {
    books := &[]models.Book{}
    // don't loads tags
    //Gdb.Order("id desc").Find(&books)
    // don't loads tags
    Gdb.Preload("Tags").Order("id desc").Find(&books).Related("Tags")

    return c.Render(books)
}
```

The db tables are there: books, tags and book_tags
Create with code first, inserting works fine.

```
func (c Book) InsertTestData() revel.Result {
    book := &models.Book{
        Title:       "Hello Go lang",
        Desctiption: "The bueaty of golang",
        Tags:        []models.Tag{{Name: "Golang"}, {Name: "Go"}},
    }

    Gdb.NewRecord(&book)
    Gdb.Create(&book)
}
```

Ah and the view code:

```
<tbody>
  {{range .books}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{.Title}}</td>
      <td>
        {{.Desctiption}}<br />
        {{range .Tags}}
          {{.Name}}
        {{end}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{end}}
</tbody>
```

In the gorm docs it says:

```
db.Model(&user).Related(&emails)
//// SELECT * FROM emails WHERE user_id = 111; // 111 is user's primary key
```

http://jinzhu.me/gorm/associations.html#many-to-many

Tags are always empty iteration over books works fine. To it (invalid association []) but works for books.

Where is the mistake and how to do it right?

Thanks for your time and help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the gorm Update yesterday eve. All (code in question) works like the docs. :)